# Will an FPGA perform better when it has a higher gate count?

Tags: fpga

I noticed that some FPGAs have the same LUTs while they have very different gate counts. Will an FPGA perform better when it has a higher gate count? What are the extra gates used for?

I mean are those FPGAs with more gates can Carry more complex circuits?

Comment: Please define "perform better".

Comment: There's no universal rule like that. It depends on technology, architecture etc.

Comment: I mean are those FPGAs with more gates can Carry more complex circuits?

Comment: Yes, of course, FPGAs that have more gates can usually handle more complex designs.  But your question asks about "performance".  What do you mean by "performance"?

Comment: FPGA metrics are all over the place. You can only directly compare numbers between the same line, sometimes not even within the same manfuacturer.

Comment: more gates/LUT provide the opportunity to perform more in parallel which could produce better peformance, if that is what you class as better performance. more gates/lut also permit things in parallel permitting lower clock freq to reduce power consumption

Comment: I noticed that some planes have the same seats while they have very different seat counts. Will a plane perform better when it has a higher seat count? What are the extra seats used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Probably marginally worse as a higher gate count implies a larger die and thus longer (and slower) signal paths. It will also have higher static power consumption making it less efficient.

Of course you can find corner cases where a specific size of design will only just fit a smaller FPGA and the resultant routing congestion makes it harder to fit all the signal paths in, where a larger device allows a more favourable (simpler and more straightforward) and thus more efficient layout.

Or a larger device allows a larger but faster design (e.g. more multipliers instead of resource sharing, or larger memories, or more parallel execution units) but all of these mean you are comparing two different designs.

So, basically no but it depends.

(All bets are off if the FPGAs are from different FPGA families : newer families can usually clock at higher speeds. But then it's the newer family that makes the difference, larger size is just incidental)